Creating a default value recursively given a type (types.GenericAlias)
Given a type t (originally comes from function annotations), I need to create a default value of that type. Normally, t() will do just that and work for many types, including basic types such as bool or int. However, tuple[bool, int]() returns an empty tuple, which is not a correct default value. It can get slightly trickier with more complex types such as tuple[bool, list[int]].
I saw that tuple[bool, int].__args__ returns (<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>), which might be useful for writing a recursive function that implements this, but I'm still having trouble with this.
Is there an existing function to do this and return the default value? If not, how would I write this code to work with all standard types?
I'm using Python 3.11.

This is not possible for the general case. A generic – type variable relationship might not be easily verifiable at runtime. You are probably having an XY problem. Show us the original problem instead.

The original problem is writing a retry decorator that will attempt to run the function several amount of times, and if it fails - will take the return type from the annotations and return a default value of that type.

Since tuple is the only instantiable standard type where the default value should not be just an instantiation of the type with no argument, you can simply special-case it in a function that recursively creates a default value for a given type:
from types import GenericAlias

def get_default_value(typ):
    if isinstance(typ, GenericAlias) and issubclass(typ.__origin__, tuple):
        return typ(map(get_default_value, typ.__args__))
    return typ()

so that:
print(get_default_value(tuple[bool, list[int]]))

outputs:
(False, [])

Demo: https://ideone.com/wlb6TL
